# android xml drawable image on full screen background

Tags: android, xml, drawable

I need an xml drawable (for a cordova splash screen) in android. I Want to display a transparent logo centered on the screen (without stretching), while the rest of the screen has a background color set.

What I tried first, was to add only the image in the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
```

This showed the logo centered on the screen, but (obviously) has no background color.

So I tried different solutions to add a background color to that xml. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now the image has a background color - but it is not full screen any more. It adjusts to the image size and gets stretched when showing as full screen.

So, how can I get a full screen drawable with background color, and a centered image on it?

**EDIT:**
All answers suggest using RelativeLayout - but I think this is not possible within an xml file in "drawable", right? I do not have any layout i can edit - only a drawable which gets referenced by cordova.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="#FFFF"></color>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Android studio shows the layout still wrong - but it works on the device as expected.

**To all posters, suggesting adding a layout-xml file:** As I stated in the question, I don't have the possibility to do that, since this drawable gets included from Cordova. I don't have control over the used layout around this drawable.

Answer (score 12):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:src="@drawable/splash" 
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical" />
```

Answer (score 2):

do this way,

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" >//Set background color

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_logo" />//set logo 

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I only have an xml file in "drawable" folder i can edit - when I try to add a RelativeLayout in this files, android studio says "Element RelativeLayout must be declared".
Are you sure it is possible to use RelativeLayout within drawable xml files?

Comment: this is xml file put this into your layout folder and set background as your drawble color xml

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for your need:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@color/bg_color"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center|bottom|clip_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: I only have an xml file in "drawable" folder i can edit - when I try to add a RelativeLayout in this files, android studio says "Element RelativeLayout must be declared".
Are you sure it is possible to use RelativeLayout within drawable xml files?

Comment: Its code for layout xml file not for drawable xml file

Comment: Well but question says "xml drawable"

Comment: still getting issue then tell me

Comment: This could work, it's close to the solution I found.  But I didn't test it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

No need to use other relative layout for background color.
You can do it using single ImageView like:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/noise"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />
```