# Splash screen image issue in cordova ! image showing blurred in cordova 4.0.2

Tags: xml, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

As per cordova application  i changed config.xml

```
    <platform name="android">
                <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/drawable-land-hdpi/screen.png" />
                <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/drawable-land-ldpi/screen.png" />
                <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/drawable-land-mdpi/screen.png" />
                <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png" />
                <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="res/drawable-land-xxhdpi/screen.png" />
                <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/drawable-land-xxxhdpi/screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/drawable-port-ldpi/screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/drawable-port-mdpi/screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/drawable-port-xxhdpi/screen.png" />
                <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/drawable-port-xxxhdpi/screen.png" />
  </platform>
```

When i start the mobile app the image will be showing blurred

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**
I encountered this testing on a device with 1024*768 resolution.
I believe it occurs when there isn't a perfectly matching resolution.

**Solution:**
I worked around this by using a **custom theme** which uses **drawable** for the splash screen instead.  This method will work for you as long as you are okay with "fit/fill/center" image display methods . (Probably not "stretch" or we will likely end up with a blurry image again anyways.)

**Note:**
This looks long, but it's actually not that bad.  I just wanted to explain thoroughly.

**My Folder Structure**

```
├───config.xml
└───res    
    └───android
        ├───drawable
        │       splash_screen.xml
        ├───drawable-hdpi
        │       splash_logo.png
        ├───drawable-ldpi
        │       splash_logo.png
        ├───drawable-mdpi
        │       splash_logo.png
        ├───drawable-xhdpi
        │       splash_logo.png
        ├───drawable-xxhdpi
        │       splash_logo.png
        ├───drawable-xxxhdpi
        │       splash_logo.png
        └───values
                style.xml
```

**splash_screen.xml**

- This is where you define what your splash screen will look like.

  - You will define how the splash_logo will be used here (fit/fill/center/colors/etc).
- This sample has a white background with the splash_logo displayed in the center.

  - Sample courtesy of [Ralf's answer to "android xml drawable image on full screen background"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29821623/5820158).
  - This should work for center and fill method (your splash_logo size will determine which actually happens).
- Android will automatically select the splash_logo icon based on the screen size/density.  More on this under *splash_logo.png*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <color android:color="#FFFF" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**splash_logo.png**

- This can be a full screen image or smaller centered icon (or whatever your heart desires).
- I found it easiest to design for xxxhdpi density screen of 1920*1280 pixels.

  - You should create your xxxhdpi density splash_logo.png with this as a reference.
  - I wanted a centered medium sized icon, so I created one icon with half height (640) and approximately square.
- We need to generate the different density images so that we will have slightly more consistent look across different devices.

  - You can see which screen sizes corresponds to which density bucket (hdpi/xhdpi/etc) [here](https://vinsol.com/blog/2014/11/20/tips-for-designers-from-a-developer/).
  - You can do this manually or use a tool.
  - I used the `Android Drawable Importer` plugin for Android Studio to generate the other density images. You can follow [erluxman's answer to "Is there a way to create xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi and ldpi drawables from a large scale image?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37321194/5820158)
- You will need to copy these files into your `/res` folder.

**style.xml**

- This is the custom theme that will use your drawable.
- Modify as desired.
- You may want to set `parent=` to whatever theme is currently being used by the main activity in `/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` (Just so that you know the theme is available in your android setup.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Full screen theme with custom splash screen -->
    <style name="MyTheme.FullScreen.Splash" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar">

        <!-- Make it full screen (since plugins don't seem to work) -->
        <!-- Remove these 2 lines if you don't want full screen -->
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

        <!-- Use our drawable for the splash screen! -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

**config.xml** (Finally)

- We need to link everything up with the config file!
- First, ensure you have this attribute=value pair inside the `<widget` tag: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
- We need to point the main activity in the manifest to our custom theme with the `edit-config` tag.

  - Courtesy of [Simon Ludwig's answer to "Change android theme from cordova config.xml"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53938237/5820158).
- And we need copy over our custom theme, drawable, and logos to Android with the `resource-file` tags.

```
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:label='@string/activity_name']">
        <activity android:theme="@style/MyTheme.FullScreen.Splash" />
    </edit-config>
    <resource-file src="res/android/values/style.xml" target="app/src/main/res/values/style.xml" />
    <resource-file src="res/android/drawable/splash_screen.xml" target="app/src/main/res/drawable/splash_screen.xml" />
    <resource-file src="res/android/drawable-ldpi/splash_logo.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-ldpi/splash_logo.png" />
    <resource-file src="res/android/drawable-mdpi/splash_logo.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/splash_logo.png" />
    <resource-file src="res/android/drawable-hdpi/splash_logo.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/splash_logo.png" />
    <resource-file src="res/android/drawable-xhdpi/splash_logo.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/splash_logo.png" />
    <resource-file src="res/android/drawable-xxhdpi/splash_logo.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/splash_logo.png" />
    <resource-file src="res/android/drawable-xxxhdpi/splash_logo.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/splash_logo.png" />
</platform>
```

That should be all!

**Troubleshooting:**

- You can check that all your resources are copied over correctly by inspecting
  `/platforms/android/app/src/main/res`.
- Ensure that your custom theme was injected into the `/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Is there a way to keep this splash screen a little bit longer? A way to add some delay?

Comment: I think you might need to use [cordova-plugin-splashscreen](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/).
You can ctrl+F for the info about "SplashScreenDelay".  We are not using this currently.  Not sure why.  Looks pretty good.  Maybe because "SplashMaintainAspectRatio" didn't work well for us.